# Create XML element without closing tag using Visual C++

Tags: xml, visual-c++

I know how to create xml element with closing tag (using WriteStartElement and WriteEndElement methods)

```
<tag id="1234">
</tag>
```

but is there a way in Visual C++ to produce xml element like this

```
<tag id="1234"/>
```

i.e. without closing tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteEndElement` will create short end tags if the node is empty.
You have to use `WriteFullEndElement` to explicitly create full end tag even if the node is empty. But in your case you mentioned that you are using `WriteEndElement` for closing the tags so it should not create full end tags.

Please verify whether the tag is empty or is it having a new line character.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made mistake, because I was actually using WriteFullEndElement, and not WriteEndElement (as I mentioned before). WriteEndElement is what I needed for this. Thanks again.